# how to get number of commit each day from xml subversion log file with javascript, php, shell script?

Tags: php, javascript, svn, shell, xml-parsing

Having XML Subversion commits log:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="2">
<author>20070299</author>
<date>2012-06-06T05:23:21.999470Z</date>
<msg>add part</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="1">
<author>20070299</author>
<date>2012-05-22T08:35:55.663875Z</date>
<msg></msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

And I want a result as array grouped by date and numbers of commit each day on my site php-javascript. similar to this one:

```
date[0]=2012-05-22
value[0]=1
date[1]=2012-05-23
value[1]=0
...
date[15]=2012-06-06
value[15]=1
```

is there a solution to do it?

I consulted this [link](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/7/getting-information-from-svn-with-php)

But it don't work, non result non error log (apache, php), and i don't know how to send $number[] from PHP code to javascript code

Answer (score 0):

You can play with XPath :

```
$ xmllint --shell foo.xml

/ > cat //log/*[@revision]/@revision
 -------
 revision="2"
 -------
 revision="1"
/ > cat //log/*[@revision]/date/text()
 -------
2012-06-06T05:23:21.999470Z
 -------
2012-05-22T08:35:55.663875Z
/ >
```

This is in a shell, but you can iterate on the XPath expressions with any languages you like instead.

**!** If anyone here knows how to tell XPath to get only the numbers in `revision="2"`, please tell us =)

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you are asking for a Linux solution but since you have not had any proffered here is a way to achieve your goal with PowerShell (and hence Windows-only). Perhaps by presenting this algorithm, another contributor can map it to Linux shell commands for you.

```
([xml](svn log -v --xml)).log.logentry |
Select-Object -Property `
        Author, `
        @{n='Revision'; e={([int]$_.Revision)}}, `
        @{n='Date';     e={Get-Date $_.Date  }}, `
        Paths | 
Group-Object {$_.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | 
Sort-Object name -Descending | 
Select-Object @{n='Date'; e={$_.Name}}, Count | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You can likely surmise what the code is doing even without fluency in PowerShell, but here is a summary of key points:

- The first line sets up an implicit loop through all log/logentry nodes.
- The first `Select-Object` statement (5 lines) pulls out XML elements and attributes converting them to fields of a PowerShell object; Revision and Date are massaged into appropriate types making them more useful than just as string data.
- The `Group-Object` statement converts what are now true date objects into a format suitable for sorting.
- The second `Select-Object` statement simply modifies the default group names (name and count) to more relevant names (date and count).
- The final `Format-Table` makes the resultant column sizes compact.

Here is a portion of output from my system:

```
Date       Count
----       -----
2012-06-29     4
2012-06-28     6
2012-06-27     8
2012-06-26    16
2012-06-25     1
2012-06-24     1
2012-06-22     5
2012-06-21     8
2012-06-20     8
```